# Mechanism to Prevent Inventory Amount for an Item Falling Below Zero

Tags: excel, vba

I have a an inventory spreadsheet consisting of a transaction table detailing in each column the date a piece of inventory is "received" into stock or "sold", description, quantity, and whether it was "received" or "sold." All of this information is fed into the table at the click of a button through a macro I have created. Is there a way using VBA that if the value of any piece of inventory falls below zero (due to trying to sell inventory not in stock) a Msgbox could be displayed and the latest line of information fed into the transaction table could be deleted?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

EDIT:

Here is the code that I'm using to populate the data from cells A4:E4 into the table called "Table1."

```
Sub PlaceOrder()

Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim LastRow As Long
Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1")
LastRow = tbl.Range.Rows.Count    'get # of last row

With ActiveSheet

'copy and paste A4
.Range("A4").Copy
tbl.Range(LastRow, 1).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

'copy and paste B4
.Range("B4").Copy
tbl.Range(LastRow, 2).Offset(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas

'copy and paste C4:F4
.Range("C4:F4").Copy
tbl.Range(LastRow, 3).Offset(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

'clear value in B4:E4
.Range("B4:E4").ClearContents
```

End With

End Sub

EDIT 2: Here is a snapshot of an old stock transaction tracker that I am using as a reference in order to create this inventory spreadsheet. It will be using a lot of the same functionality. So.... I'd like to use the value in the table column "Qty" that corresponds with the value in the table column "Stock (Exchange:Ticker)" in order to determine if an item falls below zero in quantity.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWbxQ.jpg)

Comment: `if inventoryValue < 0 Then`? How do you expect us to help you without showing us your code?

Comment: Hi Raymond. I included the code that I'm using to populate the data into the table. I apologize for leaving it out. I wasn't sure that it would be much help.

Comment: It's not as simple as if inventoryValue < 0 Then ......... I'm concerned about if any piece of inventory < 0...

Comment: Can you clarify how do you determine if the value of the inventory falls below 0? Is there a cell/worksheet/table to check against? Neither your question nor code explains this. We need specific information, it will be great if you can include a screenshot of the table and anything that is relevant.

Comment: @isinkzat, what are your column labels? Which column is what data. That will help me.

Comment: I provided a snapshot of an old stock tracker that I created. I'd like to base the inventory spreadsheet off of the format of this.

Comment: @isinkzat Based on the screenshot, is my understanding correct that 1) The input in "Symbol" (B4) will first match (partially I assume) the **last** entry of the "Stock(Exchange:Ticker)" then 2) Check if the "Qty" column of the matched row is less than zero (i.e. negative)? And lastly, this check is only necessary if the input in "Action" is sell?

Comment: You are correct with #1. For #2, the issue I can't wrap my head around is how to check if sum of the "Qty" for a given item in the Stock (Exchange:Ticker) column is below zero. For instance in the screenshot you can see that GENERAL ELECTRIC is listed 10 times. How can I check to make sure that the sum of GE or any item that appears in the transaction table is less than zero. I'm not sure.

Comment: In reference to your last comment. The check doesn't have to necessarily be done when the action is "Sell." In the "Qty" column  I simply inserted a formula that states =IF([@Type]="Sell",[@Units]*-1,[@Units]*1) .....this is just to make sure that the quantity of an item is negative when sold.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, try this version:

EDIT:

```
Sub PlaceOrder()
    With ActiveSheet
        Dim tbl As ListObject
        Set tbl = .ListObjects("Table1")
        
        Dim LastRow As Long
        LastRow = tbl.Range.Rows.Count    'get # of last row

        '====== Copy all content `
        'copy and paste A4
        .Range("A4").Copy
        tbl.Range(LastRow, 1).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

        'copy and paste B4
        .Range("B4").Copy
        tbl.Range(LastRow, 2).Offset(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas

        'copy and paste C4:F4
        .Range("C4:F4").Copy
        tbl.Range(LastRow, 3).Offset(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

        'clear value in B4:E4
        .Range("B4:E4").ClearContents
    End With
    
    Dim stockList As Variant
    Dim qtyList As Variant
    stockList = tbl.ListColumns("Stock (Exchange:Ticker)").DataBodyRange.Value
    qtyList = tbl.ListColumns("Qty").DataBodyRange.Value
    
    '=== Start checking inventory of all stocks ===
    Dim inventoryDict As Object
    Set inventoryDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim i As Long
    
    'Get a unique list of stocks
    For i = 1 To UBound(stockList, 1)
        If inventoryDict.Exists(stockList(i, 1)) Then
            inventoryDict(stockList(i, 1)) = inventoryDict(stockList(i, 1)) + qtyList(i, 1)
        Else
            inventoryDict.Add stockList(i, 1), qtyList(i, 1)
        End If
    Next i
    
    'Loop through each stock and check if it's < 0
    Dim dictItem As Variant
    For Each dictItem In inventoryDict
        If inventoryDict(dictItem) < 0 Then
            'Inventory is negative
            MsgBox "Display Message that inventory is not in stock" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                    dictItem & ": " & inventoryDict(dictItem)
            tbl.ListRows(tbl.ListRows.Count).Delete
            Exit For
        End If
    Next dictItem
End Sub
```

This will do the following:

1. Enter the data in `A4:F4` in a new row (unchanged)
2. Get a list of unique stock in column "Stock (Exchange:Ticker)" and sum up qty of the same stock.
3. Loop through each stock and check if it's < 0, display Msgbox and delete the last row (which is the data that was just entered).

Comment: Thank you for the help, but this is not working. Basically, I'm looking for if there is anyway to identify the sums of the unique values in the "Stock(Exchange:Ticker)" column in "Table1" and have an alert come up letting me know if the sum of any of those is less than zero.

Comment: @isinkzat Have edited the code, please try the new version!